# Gem Dependency Problems With Legacy App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've inherited a rails 2.2 app and I'm having some trouble getting my local enviornment configured in a way that will allow me to work.  Booting WEBrick gives me the following error:

```
./script/server
=> Booting WEBrick...
/Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:224:in `specification': undefined method `version_requirements=' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x10b1ec6a0> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/locator.rb:81:in `plugins'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `inject'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/locator.rb:81:in `each'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/locator.rb:81:in `inject'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/locator.rb:81:in `plugins'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:63:in `locate_plugins'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:62:in `map'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:62:in `locate_plugins'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:27:in `all_plugins'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:22:in `plugins'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:45:in `add_plugin_load_paths'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:269:in `add_plugin_load_paths'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:135:in `process'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `send'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `run'
from /Users/swachtma/htdocs/skating_circle/config/environment.rb:20
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:59
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@skating/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/swachtma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from ./script/server:3
```

I suspect I may need to downgrade my version of ruby-gems but I'm at a loss as to how to determine and appropriate version.

```
These are my local gems:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.2.2)
actionpack (2.2.2)
activerecord (2.2.2)
activeresource (2.2.2)
activesupport (2.2.2)
aws-s3 (0.6.3)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.2.3)
contacts (1.2.4)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
gdata (1.1.1)
heywatch (1.2.0)
highline (1.6.15)
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11)
hpricot (0.8.6)
json (1.7.6)
mime-types (1.19)
mini_magick (3.4)
net-ssh (2.6.3)
rack (1.5.1)
rails (2.2.2)
rake (10.0.3, 0.8.7)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.12.0, 1.3.2)
rspec-core (2.12.2, 2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.12.1, 2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.12.2, 2.6.0)
rspec-rails (1.3.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubygems-update (1.4.2)
rvideo (0.9.3)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
subexec (0.2.2)
will_paginate (2.2.2)
xml-simple (1.1.2)
```

Comment: what is your gem version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Rails 2.2 gem version 1.4.2 works I guess. Try downgrading to 1.4.2

```
  sudo gem update --system 1.4.2 or rvm install rubygems 1.4.2
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me pointed in the right direction.  I ended up running: $ gem install rubygems-update -v 1.3.7
$ update_rubygems _1.3.7_ and that got me sorted with this problem at least.  Found more details on rubygems-update docs that helped: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
gem install rubygems-update -v='1.4.2'
gem uninstall rubygems-update -v='1.5.0'
update_rubygems
```

Also, refer to these questions:

[Gem dependency error in rails 2.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065523/gem-dependency-error-in-rails-2-3-4)

[ruby on rails: undefined method "version_requirements' when attempting to start server after new install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286474/ruby-on-rails-undefined-method-version-requirements-when-attempting-to-start)